# How do I insert a VBA If/Else If/Else statement into MS Access Table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am the most "computer savvy" person at my job. I know very little about Access and will need an explanation of this in layman's terms. Appologies.

SO... We have a form that data is entered on with the corresponding Table where the data is stored. We go to different places and do screenings with paper which require us to manually enter the data electronically. For the new year, they want us to enter the County for each of the persons we screen. The problem becomes, we don't know ALL of the area codes that make up the counties we visit regularly. My goal was to make an If/ElseIf/Else statements so when we type in the Zip Code - the county auto populates in the county field.

I included "Else" because there are Zip Codes less commonly visited, I'm just trying to save as much time as possible. I chose not to do Nested If/Then statements so I didn't have to keep track of 100+ ")" for closing out my arguments.

I've tried [the syntax here for If/ElseIf/Else](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/if_then.php); but, I keep getting "syntax error (missing operator) in table-level validation expression." I don't know how to trouble shoot what I am doing incorrectly.

```
If [Zip Code] ="XXXXX" Then
   [County] = "North"

ElseIf [Zip Code] = "YYYYY" Then
   [County] = "South"
   
ElseIf [Zip Code] = "ZZZZZ" Then
   [County] = "East"
   
Else
   [County] = ""

End If
```

From the "Else" part - I just don't want it to populate. I thought placing nothing here would just leave it blank. I am trying to do this from the Table, not the Form. The table title for the zip code field is "Zip Code" and the title of the county field is "County."

There are two drop down boxes at the top of the VBA script screen. One says "General" one says "Description." When I select "General," It populates a list of all the Title Fields in the table. I've tried selecting "Zip Code" which gives me options like "BeforeUpdate" or "AfterUpdate" where description was.

This is all I can think of between telling you: what I want, what I'm trying to do, and what I think is relevant information. I will gladly give you more information if there is something I don't realize is important.

Comment: You did not forget to `End If` I suppose. Is the field `Country` set to `required` in the table design?

Comment: I don't think your code has anything to do with the error. From where is this code called?

Comment: *"syntax error (missing operator) in table-level validation expression."* means: Open your table in design mode, open the property sheet, and check the table ValidationRule.

Comment: @A.S.H no, I forgot to add that in the example - It is there in the actual VBA string, though; edited my original message to reflect this. Thanks... Also, I no longer have it in front of me will have to check in the AM. Will report back then.

Comment: What do you mean "From where is this code called" @Andre451? The data is entered on the Form, the data is actually stored in the Table, they have a dependency link, and I am opening the VBA Prompt from the Table design view.

Comment: Hmm. What VBA Prompt? (What exactly do you do to open this?) What Access version do you use?

Comment: Ok, but just in case, if you find that the field `Country` is `required` (check that in the Design View of the table), then probably changing `[County] = ""` into `[County] = "unspecified"` might fix it. Good luck :)

Comment: @Andre451 when in table view it is alt+F11 (maybe just F11?). And I use MS Access 2010 on a Windows 7 PC at work (where this is taking place).

Comment: You would be much better off with a look-up table of zip and county.

Comment: @Fionnuala That looks like it might work as well. I will give that a shot if the other solutions for the If/Then/Else statements do not fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: The [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx) might be simpler to maintain than "If/ElseIf/Else"

Comment: I have to ask again: where does this code "live"? It must be inside a Sub or Function - please post the full sub/function. Or perhaps post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To use If/Then/Else logic in a query, use the IIF function.  Links:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg241307%28v=office.14%29.aspx
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

So something like:
Country: iif([ZipCode]="12345","North","")

And you can nest iif() statements.

You could also create a VBA function and call it from the query.  So something close to what you have in your question, then in the query do:
Country: MyFunction([ZipCode])